# Customizing how Pull Request completion changes the associated work items

Tags: azure, tfs, pull-request

Is it possible to customize how PR Completion changes the associated work items?  I know I have a "remember" toggle under `Project Settings -> Repositories -> <Repo Name> -> work item transition preferences` and `Complete associated work items after merging` in the PR itself, but all I get in my associated work item is `Completing Pull Request 1234 and the associated work items`

What I'd really like is `Completing !1234 and the associated work items` (where that is a link to the PR, not just the text).  But I can't see how one would set that up.

My use case is that I'm walking the tree of work items and I want to peruse which PR fixed what.  I have to go all caveman and type things, when all I want to do is click.

Is there something I can customize to get what I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem, but i'm afraid currently it's not supported to customize how PR Completion changes the associated work items.

When we complete the PR, the message `Completing Pull Request 1234 and the associated work items` is automatically added to the work item, there's no option to customize it.

[image: If you'd like the]

If you would like the feature, it's recommended to raise a user voice ticket in [link](https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas), thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  Have created [an issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Customizing-how-Pull-Request-completion-/10533925).